# Changed Gmail password but still someone has access

Tags: gmail, security, account-management, hacked

A few weeks ago I noticed that there was a weird device from a location I've never been to authorized in my Google Account.

The thing is, I do have 2 step auth, and I definitely never authorized it.

So I promptly removed it, changed passwords. All good.

Then today I noticed that still there is someone logged in:

[image: 0]

Is there anything else I can do to block that?

BTW, my current devices are:
My PC, an iPhone, an iPad and a PS4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- log in to your Gmail - **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/**
- on the bottom right there is **Last account activity:**
- click on **Details**
- click on **<kbd>Sign out of all other Gmail web sessions</kbd>** button
- change your password

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for your help! I did remove that device from the security check, and now I tried your suggested and changed PW again. 
After changing password yesterday I was still seeing the unknown device. Hopefully it is permanently logged out now.
Thanks! :)